# php mysql user login show user exists

Tags: php, mysql, forms, authentication, phpmyadmin

I'm going through a vid tutorial on creating a user reg & login form in php and mysql.

The following script should echo 'exists' on the login.php form, however just shows a blank (indicating the user does not exist, when it does and s in fact the only username on the DB)

```
<?php
    function user_exists($username) {
   $username = sanitize($username);
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"); 
   return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
 }
?>
```

The login form portion of code goes as follows:

```
if (user_exists('andy') === true) {
echo 'exists';
}
die();
```

Am I missing some syntax or something obvious?? here is a link to the vid tutorial if it helps http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Til3oVNlho4

Comment: What's your OS? Your BLANK screen - does it have any message on it? Perhaps you don't have a database connection open. Is there any other code on your page?

Comment: That serie of tutorials contains a lot of bad practice: from using deprecated functions like mysql_query to vulnerable concepts by using md5 for password hashing, and a lot more. If you want to do it right, then I recommend to read a *good* book.

Comment: What happens if you run the query by itself in a mysql tool instead of on the web with php?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**warning**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @tereško Funny you should say that. The link for the tutorial you provided the OP is also `mysql_`, and not `mysqli`, so why keep the OP on the same track? ;)

Comment: @Fred There is a difference between `mysql_` **functions** which are deprecated and a `mysql` **database**. The tutorial teresko provided shows how to use `PDO` with a `mysql` *database*.

Comment: I've tried books but never seem to grasp them as usefully as with projects like these. Does anyone know of a similar video tut that's a bit more updated?

Comment: The blank screen btw is just a web page at localhost/whateverthepagewas

Comment: @HamZa could recommend any project based tutorials? You seem to know your stuff!

Comment: @user2595470 Not really, in fact I was like you following tutorials on youtube etc... Until I dove in the world of security. Basically most tutorials (especially video ones) are just there to "begin" with a bad start, I must say I've learned a lot of them. But if there is no one to give you some guidance, then you will use all the bad things you learned there in real world situations, which is extremely dangerous and bad. Fortunately now, there is SO and security.stackexchange ! There are a lot of questions/answers on how to do it the right way :)

Comment: I really don't want to read my old code :p

Answer (score 0):

Why not do like this?

```
<?php
function user_exists($username) {
$username = sanitize($username);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"); 
$exists = mysql_num_rows($query) == 1 ? 1 :0;

return $exists; 
}
?>
```

Comment: I see what you're getting at here but I think the idea was to test the DB connection and functionality with that second script on the second page..

Answer (score 0):

if you have a blank screen it might be an idea to add echo statements to see what is happening.

```
function user_exists($username) {        echo '|Input Username=$username ';
  $username = sanitize($username);       echo '|Sanitized=$username ';
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"); 
                                         echo '|output any mysql_error '.mysql_error();
  $numberOfRows = mysql_num_rows($query); echo '|Number of Rows=$numberOfRows ';
  $hasRows = ($numberOfRows > 0);         echo '|Has rows=$hasRows ';
  //used explicit parentheses around logic for clarity...and again next line
  $exists = ($hasRows) ? 1 :0;
  //or just do this...
  $exists = $hasRows;
  return $exists;     
}
```

Comment: Well that's what the echo 'exists' statement on the login page was for, and that's the screen that's blanking..

Comment: That needs to return true, the above was aimed to work out why it does not. Another idea is to use == instead of === Which is 'identity'. true is native and user_exists() is an object. they may both ==true but only true===true.

Comment: Ah apologies I see what you mean now, I'll give it a try! If this doesn't work I'll have to swap tutorials, seems to be no way round it!

Comment: Did you manage to make this work yet? On the video, he returns a boolean from user_exists() which is different to the integer 1 or 0. That would be false for 1===true, because the types don't match.